# mpl_finance cannot convert -100000 to a date

Tags: python, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I am trying to make a simple candlestick ohlc chart with mpl_finance. On their website, it says that the first element in the quotes argument of the candlestick_ohlc method is the dates. It says that they must be formatted in the float date format. When i use date2num however, it gives me an error that says"Cannot convert -100000 to a date. This often happens if non-datetime values are passed to an axis that expects datetime objects." When i use my original list without the date2num method, it gives me an error that points to a line of code- xy=(t-OFFFSET, lower) and a 
 message -"unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'float'. it seems as if it wants me to use a float instead of a datetime.date but that contradicts the previous error. Here is my code. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import requests
import json
import pprint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime, date, time

url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query"

function = "TIME_SERIES_DAILY"
symbol = "MSFT"
api_key = "K2H0JNUZBWYKW02L"

data = { "function": function, 
     "symbol": symbol, 
     "apikey": api_key } 
page = requests.get(url, params = data)
thedata = page.json()
days = []
dailyopen = []
dailyclose = []
dailyhigh = []
dailylow = []
dailyvol = []
delimitedyear = []
delimitedday = []
delimitedmonth = []

thedatakeys = list(thedata['Time Series (Daily)'].keys())
thedatakeys.sort()

for day in thedatakeys:
    days.append(day)
    dailyopen.append(float(thedata['Time Series (Daily)'][day] 
   ['1. open']))
    dailyhigh.append(float(thedata['Time Series (Daily)'][day] 
   ['2. high']))
    dailylow.append(float(thedata['Time Series (Daily)'][day] 
   ['3. low']))
    dailyclose.append(float(thedata['Time Series (Daily)'] 
   [day]['4. close']))
    dailyvol.append(float(thedata['Time Series (Daily)'][day] 
   ['5. volume']))

counter = 0
for day in days:
    delimitedyear.append(days[counter][0:4])
    delimitedmonth.append(days[counter][5:7])
    delimitedday.append(days[counter][8:10])
    counter = counter + 1
d = []

for newcounter in range(len(delimitedyear)):
    d.append(date(int(delimitedyear[newcounter]), 
int(delimitedmonth[newcounter]), 
int(delimitedday[newcounter])))

formatteddates = mdates.date2num(d)
ohlc = [formatteddates, dailyopen, dailyhigh, dailylow, 
dailyclose]
print(formatteddates)

fl, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,5))
candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc, width=.6, colorup='green', 
colordown='red')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))

ax.grid(False)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the input to `candlestick_ohlc` needs to be a list of `(datetime, open, high, ...)` tuples, or the respective numpy array.
Here you are providing a list of `[[datetime1, datetime2, ...], [open1, open2, ...], ...]` instead.

To convert to the required format, you may e.g. use

```
ohlc = list(zip(formatteddates, dailyopen, dailyhigh, dailylow, dailyclose))
```